# Как изменять свойство Visibility с помощью VisualState

Tags: c#, uwp

Никак не могу изменить свойство `Visibility` через `VisualStateManager` с кастомным `StateTrigger`. Перепробовал разные варианты.

Вот сам `UserControl`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateA">
    <UserControl>
        <StackPanel Padding="5,0,0,5"
                    x:Name="StackA"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Margin="10">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="NowState">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Now">
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <triggers:BooleanDataTrigger
                                triggers:BooleanDataTrigger.TriggerValue="True"
                                triggers:BooleanDataTrigger.DataValue="{Binding IsRec}"/>
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="StackA.Background" Value="{StaticResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="NotNow">
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <triggers:BooleanDataTrigger
                                triggers:BooleanDataTrigger.TriggerValue="False"
                                triggers:BooleanDataTrigger.DataValue="{Binding IsRec}"/>
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="StackA.Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <TextBlock x:Name="StatusText"
                       Text="Now watching:"
                       Style="{StaticResource BaseTitleStyle}"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstTitle}"
                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Свойство `Background` изменяется без вопросов.

Первый вариант для `Visibility` так же через `Setter` текст виден при любом значении `IsRec`:

```
<Setter Target="StatusText.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
```

Второй вариант через `Storyboard` тоже самое:

```
 <Storyboard>
     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StatusText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 </Storyboard>
```

На данный момент сделано через конвертер, но хотелось бы узнать почему не получается это реализовать через `VisualStateManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кто ищет, тот всегда находит.

И помог [данный](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753148/8494155) ответ на SOen.

`TextBlock` необходимо было инициализировать начальным значением `Visibility`. В данном случае это `Collapsed`. Без этого не будет работать.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="StatusText"
           Text="Now watching:"
           Visibility="Collapsed"
           Style="{StaticResource BaseTitleStyle}"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Далее использовал вот такой `Setter` в `VisualState`:

```
<Setter Target="StatusText.(TextBlock.Visibility)" Value="Visible"/>
```